# Best practice for button states on an android tablet/new device

Tags: android, android-button

Android SDK suggests developing button states (if on a custom background) around Normal, Disabled, Focussed, Focussed + Pressed and Focussed + Disabled etc.

What I have observed is that mainly android tablets and modern phones, they all have given up on a trackball and nobody really supports them.  So in that case, focussed and the related states are something that will never become visible.

Is it necessary to include all those states?  Or, can I intelligently save some APK file size by avoiding those graphics currently.

Please send your thoughts.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inputting my point of view myself.  I have included all the states as of now because I think its best from a standards perspective and I think of one situation when users will really encounter the state where focussed styles have to be shown.  I imagine the case when users have external hardware (like a bluetooth keyboard) attached and it somehow enables them to move to those buttons using the arrow key.

Please comment in your thoughts around this perspective too

Comment: This is just a small addendum, not worthy of its own answer: Keep in mind that any future devices MAY include trackballs or, as you said, external hardware that can focus a disabled field. You're best to stick to all possible states.